# Schedule python, jobs keep running

Tags: python, schedule

I set up my schedule as follows:

```
def job():
   my code

schedule.every().day.at("06:03").do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("09:56").do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("13:47").do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("17:15").do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("20:34").do(job) 
schedule.every().day.at("23:46").do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("02:57").do(job)

while True:
   schedule.run_pending()
   sleep(1)
```

However, the job sometimes takes 1 hour and some other time it takes 10 hours. The problem arises when the job takes the longest (10 hrs). As soon as it ends it seems like the schedule decides to run again all the jobs it has been missing within those 10 hours.

How can I fix that?

Usually, the job needs to sleep for 10 hours when a boolean becomes True otherwise if the boolean is False the job takes around 1 hour. Is it possible to fix this issue by adjusting the infinite loop as follows?

```
while True:
   if my_boolean == True:
      sleep(10*60*60)
      my_boolean == False
   else:
      schedule.run_pending()
      sleep(1)
```

Comment: _As soon as it ends it seems like the schedule decides to run again all the jobs it has been missing within those 10 hours._ You want to make it so that at each of those times the job only runs if it isn't currently running? Am I understanding things correctly? _Usually, the job needs to sleep for 10 hours when a boolean becomes True otherwise if the boolean is False the job takes around 1 hour._ It "sleeps" 10 hours, or it takes 10 hours to execute? _Is it possible to fix this issue by adjusting the infinite loop as follows?_ All of this is quite abstract, can you share the actual code?

Comment: Yeah exactly, so it skips some jobs and therefore it runs all of them after the 10 hrs have been passed. So basically, when my job runs it usually sleeps for one hour or 10 hours depending on a Boolean value which is created. What I want is that in the moment the job is of 10 hrs then if schedule misses some job it shouldn’t run them all together, but it should follow the schedule again. 
I was thinking that I could return tho Boolean from my job and then apply that proposed solution I put in the question. I hope it’s clear.

Comment: Also it sleeps 10 hrs it doesn’t run for 10 hrs.

Comment: Are the sleeping 10 hours and working for 10 hours referring to different things? I’m a bit confused, sorry.

Comment: Okay I’ll try to explain it again. No worries. So during my job something can happen which might turn this Boolean from being true to being false. When the variable is true the job ends and everything is good, I wait till the next schedule. However, when the Boolean is false i literally set a sleeping time of 10 hrs. 
When the sleeping time is over the schedule should keep working as usual, however what happens is that the schedule runs all the job it has been missing in those 10 hours. I hope it’s clear now, I can try to explain more if you need :)

Comment: Basically, I want to make sure that if job takes 10 hrs then the scheduled jobs that have been skipped are not run one after each other, instead, the "history" of jobs is cleaned and everything starts again from the next scheduled time. 

Example: if I have scheduled a job at 13:00, 15:00, and 17:00 and the job at 13 takes 10 hours the issue is that the jobs at 15 and 17 are gonna be queued and ran right after the 10 hours. Instead what I want is to delete those jobs that have been waiting and starts again from the next job which would be once again the one at 13:00